# Utilizar Ajax no CakePHP 2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

Não consigo utilizar a sintaxe normal do **Ajax** no **CakePHP**. Já vi algumas coisas sobre o **JsHelper**, mas não consigo fazer o que quero.

Como posso chamar uma `action` do `controller` por **Ajax** enviando determinados dados e depois receber o resultado da `action` na `view`?

Comment: Posta o código que você tentou, vai facilitar pra tentarmos visualizar o problema e ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo, é esse o caminho que você está seguindo utilizando o [**JsHelper**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html). Primeiro você precisa incluir o *helper* em seu `Controller`:

```
public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

E para exemplificar, você tem um método assim que irá retornar um `array` contendo alguns parâmetros:

```
public function ajax() {
    $this->render(false, false);
    debug($this->request->params);
}
```

A `View` correspondente a um outro *Controller* (`teste_ajax`, por exemplo) vamos colocar apenas um botão, passando dois parâmetros, **foo** e **bar**:

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Enviar', array('update' => '#response', 'url' => array('action' => 'ajax', 'foo', 'bar')));
echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('inline' => 'true'));
echo "<div id='response'></div>";
```

Note que eu defini para exibir minha resposta no elemento **#response**, que é minha `div` da última linha.

Veja está claro e você consegue entender para poder implementar de acordo com suas necessidades.

Comment: Recomendo esta forma por usar recursos do próprio framework.

Comment: Valeu! Funcionou!

Comment: Bom poder ajudar! Não se esqueça de marcar essa resposta como aceita, assim poderá ajudar outros com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei de Cake, trabalho com Codeigniter, mas não deve ser muito diferente. O que faço é, no action do ajax chamo o controller e o mais simples é dar um echo (não é o mais recomendado, apenas para teste) e o valor impresso do echo recebo no return do success. Algo assim:

js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/action',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {chave:valor},
    success: function (retorn) {
        $('#content').html(retorn); //colocar o retorno no #content
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Erro');
    }
});
```

php:

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function action()
    {
         echo "teste";
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude